# Como fazer um redirect na barra de endereços com php ex: /abrir/?pagina=?

Tags: php

exemplo:

community/?subtopic=characters

dashboard/?pagina=ng

como que configuro minha pagina em php para ficar desse jeito?
qual nome dessa função ?
onde tem um tutorial pra isso também?

Comment: url amigaveis? seria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem sobre qual parte é a sua dúvida, então vou dividir em duas respostas.

Primeiramente, o que acontece com esse `/?` é que geralmente o endereço da página em si (`index.php`, na maioria dos casos) é ocultado, mas a página retornada ainda é o `index.php` (ou outra, definido no servidor). Então os parâmetros seguidos de `?` ainda são repassados para a página normalmente.

Em outras palavras:
`community/?subtopic=characters` e `community/index.php?subtopic=characters` **são a mesma coisa**.

Agora, se você está se referindo à condicionar o conteúdo de uma página com base nos parâmetros, dê uma lida sobre o [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Você pode usá-lo para fazer algo do tipo:

```
<?php
    $Pagina = $_GET['pagina'];

    if($Pagina == "perfil") {
        include("Perfil.inc.php");
    } else if($Pagina == "login") {
        include("Login.inc.php");
    }
?>
```

Quando o usuário acessar `/index.php?pagina=login` (ou ainda `/?pagina=login`), você poderá exibir uma tela de login e etc.

Obs: **Nunca** faça um `include` diretamente de um parâmetro `$_GET`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
    $Pagina = $_GET['pagina'];

    include($Pagina);
?>
```

ou

```
<?php
    include($_GET['pagina']);
?>
```

Isso cria uma enorme brecha de segurança em seu site. Sempre valide os parâmetros ou faça por associação, como no exemplo que eu passei lá em cima.